# Dot product A by each row of B in a new array

Tags: numpy, matrix

I have two matrices:

```
# Matrix A 2x1
A = np.array([[2],
              [3]])

# Matrix B 3x3
B = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9]])
```

I want to create a new multidimensional array of matrices like `[A.B(row1), A.B(row2), A.B(row3)]`. I can do it like this:

```
# Matrix A 2x1
A = np.array([[2],
              [3]])

# Matrix B 3x3
B = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9]])
C = []
for b_row in B:
    C.append(A.dot([b_row]))
C = np.array(C)

print(C)
```

```
[[[ 2  4  6]
  [ 3  6  9]]

 [[ 8 10 12]
  [12 15 18]]

 [[14 16 18]
  [21 24 27]]]
```

How can I create this, for any B columns number, without loops?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) than a dot product, but you can solve this with broadcasting if you add a new axis to B where you want A's elements to be broadcast to.

```py
A * B[:, np.newaxis, :]
```

Comment: `A @ B[:, np.newaxis, :]` also works.  In this version of `dot`, with (2,1) and (3,1,3) shapes, the sum-of-products is on the shared size 1 dimension, and the `2` is a 'batch' dimension, functioning the same way as the OP's row iteration.

Comment: Oops, the first 3 of B is the `batch`

Comment: And can also do A @ B[:, None, :]